# How to handle power distribution on a robot?

Tags: raspberry-pi, electric

Our team just finished the [FRC competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIRST_Robotics_Competition) and I am trying to learn more about robots in general. I'm trying build a robot in a similar setting than the FRC competition. However the RobotRIO is out of my budget.

I'm currently set on buying a Raspberry PI 3B as main controller board as replacement for the robotRIO.

However, I do not quite understand how I'm going to power 12v motor. In our FRC build we had this [power distribution panel](http://www.andymark.com/cross-the-road-power-distribution-panel-p/am-2856.htm), but I'm pretty sure I will fry my raspberry PI.

I believe I need some kind of power distribution board to have 5v and 2.5a for the Raspberry PI. And also 12v on some other pin. Does this exist or am I looking for something that do not exist.

My build would be powered by a 12v battery like these [Interstate Batteries (am-3062)](http://www.andymark.com/power-patrol-sla1116-12-volt-18ah-batteries-2-pack-p/am-3062.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For power management, you can use either a DC/DC Convertor, a linear regulator, or a combination of the two.

**DC/DC Converter**

A [DC/DC Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter) changes DC voltage levels.  Three common types are:

1. [Buck Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter): Takes a higher input voltage to a lower output voltage
2. [Boost Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter): Takes a lower input voltage to a higher output voltage
3. [Cuk Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%86uk_converter): A combination of a boost and buck converter that can take an input voltage and either boost or drop it.

**Linear Regulator**

A [linear regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator) also takes a higher input voltage and provide a lower output voltage.  Typically, the output voltage is "cleaner" with less noise than a DC/DC converter and you will find regulators used to power embedded computers and microcontrollers.

**System Recommendations**

You can use a Cuk Converter between your battery and the 12V motors.  You can also use a 5V regulator to get the necessary power to your Raspberry Pi.  Instead of using the power distribution panel, you can try everything on a breadboard and then move to a perfboard.  Many of these parts should be available on Digikey, Adafruit, or the electronics vender of your choice.